# Save on device without getting deleted once app is deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to save something on the device programmatically without it being deleted once the app is deleted? Also, without having my app rejected.

Comment: Does it need to be on the device? You could do this via iCloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can save some data in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), which will persist if you app is delete. But it will be removed if the device is reset.